# how to changing the Android Toolbar item hover/pressed color?

Tags: android, toolbar, styling

For some reason I've been having a lot of trouble tracking down how to change the press state/hover state color of the Android toolbar items. I was wondering if someone would show an example of how to do this. Right now it's just defaulting to a light gray color.

here's my toolbar code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/overflowStyle"
 >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here's my toolbar style code so far:

```
    <style name="overflowStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">
        @drawable/actionbar_background_states
    </item>
</style>
```

I have a drawer, a drop down spinner, and an overflow menu connected to this toolbar, each item I'd like to have a blue pressed color.

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you got solution for this???

Comment: @Sanu No. I'm still looking.

Comment: thanks for your replay. It is possible.We can see in the default message app have this capability. If we check ,the hover color is something similar to gray (light).and the toolbar color is changing for different messages. :)